# using ArrayList for counting

Tags: java, arraylist

on my following code, I have 2 counters so I used an ArrayList , as I want to get number of each counted items outside loop.
I've used arrayList as follow which gives me the expected values at print, but I would like to know if I can optimize my code using array [] , collections instead of list to avoid to to twice list.add(cout1);list.add(count2)?

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      int count1 = 0;
      int count2 = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i < nb; i++)
      {

        if (action)
        {
          counter1++;

        }
        if (votherAction)
        {
          counter2++;

        }

      }
    list.add(count1);
    list.add(count2);
```

Comment: It is very unclear what you mean. If you know you have two counters, and you have two variables for them, why do you want to put them into a collection? And what do you mean by *tables*?

Comment: Are there counters for printing purpose only?

Comment: I just want to count number of string1 if(action1) number of strings2 if(action2) so I have 2 counters , and I would like to know if there a a way to make the cound without adding twice count1,count2 to the list?

Answer (score 2):

You can use FluentUtils.pair() instead of ArrayList (http://code.google.com/p/fluentutils/)
like return pair(counter1, counter2)

Answer (score 0):

Use to produce arraylist: 
    Arrays.asList(count1, count2)

Comment: ok, so here I have to remove : ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add them to a `String` and need not to use `ArrayList`. 
You can use this to print.

```
String counterStr = "Count 1 : " + count1 + ", Count 2 : " + count2;
```

Edit: You can use `Array` instead of `ArrayList`.

```
int[] countArr = new int[2];
...
countArr[0] = counter1;
countArr[1] = counter2;
```

Comment: no, I didn't use only to print , I would like to use values of my count1, count2 outside the loop and would like to know if there is a better way then mine to do it

Comment: I have to use the content of counters outside loop

Comment: You can use `countArr` outside.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that

```
int[] counter = new int[2];

      for (int i = 0; i < nb; i++)
      {

        if (action)
        {
          counter[0]++;

        }
        if (votherAction)
        {
          counter[1]++;

        }

      }
```

but the benefice is minimal